# changing the first welcome output when logging in via ssh

Tags: ssh

I was just wondering on CentOs how can I change the 'greeting' that the server output when a user logs in via ssh?

Comment: logins in via ssl?  Or ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking to update the content that is part of the Message of the Day (MOTD).  I believe this is /etc/motd on Centos.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean ssh.

Modify /etc/issue as root to put whatever text you wish.

Comment: silly me :)
yeah i meant ssh, but /etc/issue contains only the centos release version.. and when i log in i get more details about the packagers and last login info and so on

Comment: Probably pulling from /etc/motd

Answer (score 1):

Check out also

```
Banner /etc/issue.net
```

inside */etc/ssh/sshd_config*: with this you can also display messages before login completes.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/motd is the file you are looking for.